# How to know the direction of Angular Acceleration vector in circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation

I am learning Rotational Dynamics. I came to know that the Direction of Angular Velocity Vector is given by right hand thumb rule. Is the Direction of angular acceleration vector also given by Right hand thumb rule ? What about in case of negative acceleration ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Direction of angular acceleration vector also given by Right
> hand thumb rule?

Yes (using $I\vec{\alpha} = \vec{r}\times\vec{F}$)

> What about in case of negative acceleration ?

You can still use the right hand rule.

Comment: Wouldn't in case of negative acceleration direction of acceleration vector changes ?

Comment: Yes, but along with the angular acceleration changing, either r or F must also change direction. Is that clear?